# Linux Sed command for multiple replacements

Tags: linux, sed

I need a help One more i need the orginal file name along with the replacement file name
My file is:

```
bmb/eng/case.bmb
```

output should be like:

```
bmb/case.bmb 
bmx/eng/case.bmx
```

The command i am using here is

```
$ echo bmb/eng/case.bmb | sed -E 's/.*/& &/;:a;s/([^ ]* [^\n]*)(bm)b/\1\2x/;ta;s~/~&eng&~2'
bmb/eng/eng/case.bmb bmx/eng/case.bmx
```

ouptput iam getting:

```
bmb/eng/eng/case.bmb bmx/eng/case.bmx
```

Comment: `sed 'p;s/bmb/bmx/g;s~/~&eng&~' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-e` option to run several sed expressions. To globally replace *bmb* with *bmx*, `s/bmb/bmx/g`. To insert the *eng* subdirectory, replace the first slash, for example `s#/#/eng/#`. In the second expression, I use hash characters to delimit the expression and the substitution so that I can just type slash without backslash.

The result:

```
$ echo bmb/case.bmb  | sed -e 's/bmb/bmx/g' -e 's#/#/eng/#'
bmx/eng/case.bmx
```

What baffles me: Your command should work as well. Instead of the `&` in the second expression, I would just use a slash, but this is just for readability. Where the *menu* comes from is not clear. Perhaps some context is missing?

Comment: Thans Bernd it works , i need the original file also
output should be like :
bmb/case.bmb
bmx/eng/case.bmx

Comment: This command works :
$ echo bmb/case.bmb  | sed -E 's/.*/& &/;:a;s/([^ ]* [^\n]*)(bm)b/\1\2x/;ta;s~/~&eng&~2'
bmb/case.bmb bmx/eng/case.bmx

is it possible to get the file name in new line without getting in the same line

Comment: Ooops I ignored your requirement to also print the original file name. Rather than trying to figure out how to do that with sed, why not pragmatically echo'ing it?

Comment: @afrin You can use `-n` option together with `p` command. The `-n` option suppresses line printing unless specified explicitly. The complete command: `sed -n -e 'p' -e '<commands-to-modify-line>' -e 'p'`. The first command prints the original line, the next - modifies it, and the last prints the modified line.

Comment: Hi All, this sed -e 's/bmb/bmx/g' -e 's#/#/eng/#' is adding eng dir in the other file type paths as well .

Comment: can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Hi Team 
Can i get help on sed command please 

i have the file as below :
bmb/eng/case.bmb

Output i need as below:
bmb/case.bmb
bmx/eng/case.bmx